# Geometry Proof Using Circle Theorem

Tags: geometry, circles

The diagonals $PR$ and $QS$ of a cyclic quadrilateral $PQRS$ intersect at $X$. The tangent at $P$ is parallel to $QS$. Prove that $PQ = PS$.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of point $R$. Since angles in alternate segments at tan are equal $PQ=PS$.